# Can we use forcing to adjoin this set to a model of ZF+j+$\alpha$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

Let $M$ be a countable transitive model of $\sf ZF + j +\alpha$, where $j:V_{\alpha+1} \to V_\alpha$ is an external [not used in separation and replacement] bijection such that for any $S \in V_{\alpha+2}$ we have both $j[S]; j^{-1}[S]$ being sets (i.e. in $M$).

Now my question is:

> can forcing be used to show that for some $\alpha$ we can adjoin the class $ \{\{j(a),j(b)\} \mid a,b \in V_{\alpha+1} \land a \cap b \neq \emptyset\}$ to a model of $\sf ZF +j + \alpha$? We do have all finite subsets of that class being already sets, can we make use of that in selecting the forcing conditions?